# jquery IE change/ click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, internet-explorer

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="sss">
    <label class="label_radio" for="radio-01">
        <input name="vtip" id="radio-01" value="50" type="radio" />
        <img src="http://www.tui-travelcenter.ro/layouts/innobyte/images/radio_50.jpg" width="199" height="241" style="display:block">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ddd">
    <label class="label_radio1" for="radio-02">
        <input name="vtip" id="radio-02" value="100" type="radio" />
        <img src="http://www.tui-travelcenter.ro/layouts/innobyte/images/radio_100.jpg" width="199" height="241" style="display:block">
    </label>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#radio-01').change(function(){ 
        $(".label_radio").css({background: "#fff"});                           
        $(".label_radio1").css({background: "#fff"});                                   

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {                                                  
             $(".label_radio").css({background: "#000"});       
        } else {
         $(".label_radio").css({background: "#f00"}) ;          
        }
     });

     $('#radio-02').change(function(){                                 
        $(".label_radio").css({background: "#fff"});                                                          
        $(".label_radio1").css({background: "#fff"}); 

        if($(this).is(":checked")) $(".label_radio1").css({background: "#000"}); 
        else $(".label_radio1").css({background: "#fff"}) ; 
     });
 });
```

I have two radio buttons, that have a custom image. On click, they change their backgrounds, so you can see that it is selected. (here is live: tui-travelcenter.ro/concurs_vouchere.php - the 2 pics.)
This works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: what version of IE are you using ?

Comment: i have tested it on IE 9 and it works perfectly :S

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Update to the latest version just to rule out any IE9 jQuery bugs.

Comment: I move that code on another site, with the latest version of jQuery and is working. It seems that here is in conflict with something...but only in IE....weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work in IE, use `$(".label_radio1").css({'background-color': "#fff"});` instead of `$(".label_radio1").css({background: "#fff"});` in your code.

Do the same in all places where you call `.css(..)`

---

**EDIT**

In IE, your click event is NOT propagating UP from the img to the label, so that it affects the radio (of which it is label of) and triggers the radio's change event. Add this code to your JS to force event propagation.

```
$('label img').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('input').attr('checked', true).change();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply, but this didn't help...I am using IE 9.0.8

Comment: I tested in IE8. In IE9 even .css('background'..) should have worked. Hmm.. Did you change the code in all the places (especially where you have specified #000 as the selection color)? Also, having a label in the background and coloring that isn't the best way to do this i'd think. You can do this cleaner with a thick border for the image itself.

Comment: Yes :( Just like you said (you can see it here : tui-travelcenter.ro/concurs_vouchere.php ). :( I hate IE...

Comment: ok found it. In IE, your click event is NOT propagating UP from the img to the label, so that it affects the radio (of which it is label of) and triggers the radio's change event. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I know this is rather late. But any idea **why** the click event is not propagating up? Curious.